# Why is the change in temperature written this way?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, water

The description of the exercise was following:

There's 170 g of water in a calorimeter with the temperature of $15°C$. A piece of copper with a mass of 210 g is placed in the water. The temperature of the water increases to $23°C$. What was the temperature of the copper before it was placed in the water?

I know that $Q_{lost}=Q_{gained}$

So the equation is like this

$\frac{4.1819\ kJ}{kg\cdot C}\cdot0.17kg\cdot\left(23°C-15°C\right)=\frac{0.387\ kJ}{kg\cdot C}\cdot0.21\ kg\cdot\left(x-23°C\right)$

I understand that the temperature difference of the water is 23°C−15°C, but why is the temperature difference of the copper x−23°C?

Could someone explain it to me, how do I know what $\Delta t$ is in this equation $Q=cm\Delta t$?

Comment: How would you analyze this differently?

Comment: "Young Albert did not like algebra, and his uncle is supposed to have aroused
his curiosity by telling him to think of it as a detective story, where x was
the criminal who had to be identified by following the “clues” in the equations.
Once the boy had grasped this idea he never looked back." Source: https://www.newscientist.com/letter/mg16922837-800-einsteins-uncle/.

Comment: Historical note: The story might be a bit apocryphal, I have heard the same story with a missing animal in a zoo instead of a missing criminal. I didn't go on a rabbit hole extravaganza and just gave the first prima facie reliable result I got from Google. But in any case, it's a nice story and illustrates the point, hopefully. Edit: See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/source-for-this-story-about-einstein-learning-algebra-from-his-uncle.

Comment: $\delta t = t_{final} - t_{initial}$, for each of the two materials. Try to figure out what $t_f$ and $t_i$ should be for the copper and the water.

Comment: Is it like this for water $t_{final}-t_{initial}$ and like this for copper $t_{initial}-t_{final}$?@electronpusher

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of sign. I think you are confused with whether it should be $T_f-23$ or $23-T_f$. The  real expression would be

First, as there is no loss of heat to the surrounding, the net heat change during the process should be zero. In other words,
$$\delta Q=0=\delta Q_1+\delta Q_2$$
$$m_1C_\text{water}(T^\text{water}_f-T^\text{water}_i)+m_2C_\text{coppor}(T^\text{copper}_f-T^\text{copper}_i)=0$$
$$m_1C_\text{water}(23-15)+m_2C_\text{copper}(23-x)=0$$
That's what you are seeing if you take the  second  term on the right side!

Comment: Your answer is wrong in terms 23-x as I think it should be x-23, because that gives me the right answer.

Comment: What's the answer?